# Having multiple Heroku Dynos - sometimes 1 of them is extremly slow in response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, unicorn, puma

Ok, so here is our setup:

We have 3 web-dynos running on Heroku with our rails application (rails with puma - we also tested unicorn). This app is connected to a postgresql DB which is quite strong (max pool_size of 120). We also tested 2 or 4 dynos

We have about 800 requests per minute hitting this API server.

Sometimes, we are getting quite large response times. The strange thing is, that it only happens on 1 web-dyno. At least this is what we can see in our logs.

The other 2 dynos are just about perfect in response time for the same route (during the time the other dyno is having huge response problems). This goes on for a couple of minutes until its back to "normal". Until its showing the same behaviour again a couple of hours later.

We can't find any pattern that would help us find out what to do about it.

Does anyone have an idea of how we can attack that problem?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: ... Contact Heroku support? It sounds like maybe there is imperfect load-balancing, and one of your dynos isn't being hit often enough to keep it awake. I thought that once you were using two dynos (Ie, you have a non-free account), they are never shutdown due to inactivity, but that might not be the case. Perhaps just the first dyno is always-on, and the rest do shut down after a certain period of inactivity, to be spun up on demand.

Comment: But seriously, *"Does anyone have an idea of how we can attack that problem?"*, yes, you attack it by contacting Heroku support.

Comment: Are you using something like New Relic, which would let you isolate those long transactions and decompose them to the individual operations?